# After doing a fresh install of Lion my app doesn't seem to be storing anything in the session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion, authlogic, cancan

I just did a fresh install of Lion and now my app doesn't seem to be able to have anything stored in the session.

What happens in my app is:

1. I navigate to the login page
2. Enter valid credentials
3. The app authenticates me ( I have verified that the @user_session.save call returns true)
4. I get redirected to the page that logged in users get redirected to
5. However, user_session is actually nil, so CanCan then raises an AccessDenied exception
6. I get redirected to the login page

Throughout this whole process no flash messages are displayed. 
Also, my app would typically save the last page that the user tried to visit when an AccessDenied exception is raised. However, nothing is in the session after I am redirected to the login page. Not even the typical "Please login" flash message.

Everything was working before my reinstall. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the fact that I was using subdomains. When I tried the site using localhost:3000, the session would not persist. However, using lvh.me fixed everything.